# Is it possible to set the letter-spacing of canvas text?

Tags: html, html5-canvas

I'm working with html5 canvas text and need to change the horizontal spacing between the characters.

Normally, I'd use CSS to set "letter-spacing", but the spec for canvas Text only allows for a "font" value:
http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/the-canvas-element.html#text-0

Is there a way to set "letter-spacing" or similar using canvas text?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Letter spacing in canvas element](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8952909/letter-spacing-in-canvas-element)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See [Letter spacing in canvas element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8952909/letter-spacing-in-canvas-element)

This answer:

> This is not possible; the HTML5 Canvas does not have all the
>   text-transformation power of CSS in HTML. I would suggest that you
>   should combine the appropriate technologies for each usage. Use HTML
>   layered with Canvas and perhaps even SVG, each doing what it does
>   best.
>
> Note also that 'rolling your own'—drawing each character with a custom
>   offset—is going to produce bad results for most fonts, given that
>   there are letter kerning pairs and pixel-aligned font hinting.